# Display numbers on grouped product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7

I've been searching for some days for a solution but can't find anything perhaps someone can help me with my problem :

I want to display the number of the product before the product name in my grouped product. I've create an attribute and put the number of the product in the product information but I don't know how to show it in the fronted, here are some pictures :

[image]

I've added the "position vue eclatee" in a phtml but I don't know how to put the right number of the product.

Comment: Do you want to display available no of stock of each product under "position vue eclatee" ?

Comment: Does the sequence right regarding to the product list and product image? If yes, why not use foreach loop and +1 after each iteration?

Comment: No i want to put the number that correspond in the picture you can see, like number 1 on the picture it's the piece noted number 1 in the list of piece on the right (Vanne Top 1.5" A Serrer). i've added a attribute in product and added the right number that correspond but i want to display it under "position vue eclatee"

We can't do a foreach loop cause some time there is 1A 1B 1C 2 3 and some times 1 2 3A 3B etc...

Comment: share your link please and let me check the things

Comment: http://vitapiscine.com/filtre-souffle-vipool-top-acis-modele-ft6-ft11-ft15-ft20.html